# Query to get all test cases in a static test suite?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using VSTS to maintain our test cases.

I have created a test suite named **Login Tests** inside test plan **foundation**, which contains all the scenarios for login validation.

I want to add all existing test cases which are in **Login Tests** to my new test plan. Currently, I am manually copying and pasting the IDs in the search query,but is there any way where I can get all the test cases inside a suite.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do as you describe.

However there is an easy workflow change that will allow you to do this. You have some manual work to get there, but once there things will be better. You should go through all of your Test Cases in the manual Suite and tag them with "tests-login".

Once done you can easily create Query Based suites anywhere with the correct list and control the list using the Tag.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yeah, it seems there is no way to get items using query.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the suit in the VSTS Test manager folder and Export to email you can select multiple suit and past in excel from email

Comment: In case of larger size you can choose chrome browser print cancel and copy the browser content to excel